# LinearLayout inside ScrollView does not expand far enough

Tags: java, android-studio, android-scrollview

I'm making a market application as a project for my university. As such I am loading products from my database and need to display them in a list for which I want to use a `ScrollView` since I am fairly certain that all of the data will not be displayable on the screen at once.

I gave the `ScrollView` and the included `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` all tags I thought necessary to contain all of that and then started adding TextViews with the informations about the products and added those into the `LinearLayout` but when trying to run this on the emulator the last object at the very bottom of the `LinearLayout` gets cut off roughly in the middle.

I've been looking around for ways to fix this after I couldn't come up with anything but nothing worked, I've seen here the ideas of making the scrollview's gravity centered and that didn't work, center_vertical didn't either, giving it the attribute `android:fillViewPort="true"` did nothing either `android:layout_weight="1"` had no effect and `android:orientation="vertical"` has been in there ever since I initialized the `ScrollView`.

So I'm kind of baffled at this because even if i try to resize the `LinearLayout` via Hardcoding it to expand by 1000px every time an object is added, that doesn't do anything, in fact up until hardcoding 6000px onto the Layout it doesn't even respond in any meaningful way and at that point it just basically duplicates itself but without any content. I don't understand what is going wrong. So this I pose as a question to you.

The following contains the XML code for the entire activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/base_content"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_basic_list">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:background="@color/base_bar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </View>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:background="@color/base_bar"
        android:contentDescription="@string/menu"
        android:textOff="+"
        android:textOn="-"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/bar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bar" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="99dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="99dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="99dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="99dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="62dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="177dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="177dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="177dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="177dp"
        android:background="@color/base_bar"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_desc"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="465dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is also the Code of the java segment that adds Views to the Layout:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jarray_stock.length(); i++){
                System.out.println(i);
                try {
                    JSONObject jobj = jarray_stock.getJSONObject(i);

                    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
//                    tv.setWidth(1000);
//                    tv.setHeight(500);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1000, 500));
//                    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.error_content));
                    tv.setX(0);
                    tv.setY(i * (40));

                    tv.append("\n  Name: " + jobj.getString("article_name"));
                    tv.append("\n  Fach: " + jobj.getString("article_module"));
                    tv.append("\n  ISBN: " + jobj.getString("ISBN"));
                    tv.append("\n  Zustand: " + jobj.getString("status"));
                    tv.append("\n\n  Verkäufer: " + jobj.getString("selling_user"));
                    tv.append("\n  Preis: " + jobj.getString("price"));
                    tv.append("\n");

                    tv.getLayoutParams().height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

                    Button jB = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                    jB.setWidth(50);
                    jB.setHeight(50);
                    jB.setX(750);
                    jB.setY(225+(i*(500 + 40)));
                    jB.setTextSize(17);
                    jB.setText(">>>");
                    jB.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    jB.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.base_active));

//                    parent_content.setMinimumHeight((jarray_stock.length() * 40) + 2000);
                    parent_content.addView(tv);
//                    parent_content.addView(jB);
                    tv.requestLayout();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Oh and the Button being created in there is not added, that line is commented out on purpose, I want to fix the problem with the `ScrollView` before fondling around with the button placement, that's also why the location assignment doesn't make any sense currently.

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: Tried that, still cutting off the bottom of the last TextView

Comment: put bottom margin to linearlayout

Comment: Done this using the android:layout_marginBottom tag with different values and that also does nothing. I also tried padding but that just made the Layout inside the ScrollView stop at a higher position